# Pass variable to dialog button

Tags: jquery, button, dialog

I have a button added to a dialog. When clicked, it gets results from the dialog and displays them on the main page. There can be a number of elements that need this done so I am trying to make one function that works with all of them. But in order to do that I need to pass the name to that function and I can't figure out how to do that without using a global var.

For example, the code below shows the dialog being called. The "which" parameter can be any number of things. in the GetResults function, the results are grabbed for whichever parameter is used. The code works fine as is but I'm trying to not use a global. Is this possible?

```
    <script>
    var gwhich = '';
    function ShowTheDialog(which) {
      var dWidth = 200; 
      var dHeight = 350; 
      var name = '';
      var thisurl = '';
      switch (which) {
        //set vars here
      }
      gwhich = which;

      $.ajax({
        url:thisurl,
        success: function(data) {
        $("#show-dialog").html(data).dialog({modal:true}).dialog({options: 
          open, 
          title:name, 
          width:dWidth, 
          height:dHeight,

          buttons: { 
             "Save": GetResults,
             "Cancel": function() {
                text:'Cancel',
                 $(this).dialog("close");
             }      
          },
         });
        }
      });
    } 
    function GetResults(){ 
      which = gwhich;
      var selectedItem = $("#retval-selected").text();
      var apply_to = $("#retval-apply-to").text();
      $("#show-selected-"+which).val(selectedItem);
      $("#show-apply-to-"+which).val(apply_to);
      $("#show-dialog").dialog( "close" );
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: how do you call the ShowTheDialog() function? is it triggered by a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the which parameter to GetResults();

```
     buttons: { 
             "Save": function() {
                GetResults(which);
             },
             "Cancel": function() {
                text:'Cancel',
                 $(this).dialog("close");
             }      
          },


   function GetResults(which){ 
      var selectedItem = $("#retval-selected").text();
      var apply_to = $("#retval-apply-to").text();
      $("#show-selected-"+which).val(selectedItem);
      $("#show-apply-to-"+which).val(apply_to);
      $("#show-dialog").dialog( "close" );
    }
```